# Greedy Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I understand that ? can be used to make modifiers only match the first occurence and prevent the greediness, but maybe I've misunderstood how it's supposed to work. If the string is:

`one two three four four four five six`

...and I want to capture `three`. I've been trying:

`^one two (.*)(four)+?.*$`

...but this gives me `three four four`. What am I doing wrong? I've tried `??` and `.?` and just `(four)?`, but it's not working.

Comment: The `(.*)` that should be greedy as well `(.*?)`.

Comment: the non-greedy qualifier belongs after the `.*` so `(.*?)`

Comment: Please refer to the "Quantifiers" section of the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496). Particularly the items regarding greediness and reluctance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do this:

```
^one two (.*?) four.*$
```

Or you can use `\S` which means non whitespace characters,

```
^one two (\\S+) four.*$
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture `three` you can simply do:

```
^one two (\w+) four
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
^one two (.*)(four)+?.*$
```

means match `one two` and then, as much as possible `(.*)`, until you see a `four`, repeatedly, followed by arbitrary characters.

Possibly you would be better off with splitting this string on white space and inspecting the words ("one",...).